# How do I cross-compile Chromium for ARM?

Tags: chrome, arm, cross-compilation, assembly

### Goal

I need to install Chromium on FriendlyARM `mini210s` running **Linux 3.0.8 armv7l**

### Environment

- Vagrant box with Ubuntu Precise64
- Installed `depot_tools` following these guidelines [Get-the-code](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) and
  [Linux Chromium ARM](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumArm)

#### Toolchain depot_tools

After getting the `depot_tools`:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/depot_tools$ fetch chromium
```

#### Environment variables

```
export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
export GYP_DEFINES="target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard"
```

### Dependencies

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/depot_tools/src$  ./chrome/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --arch=arm 
Installing Debian Wheezy arm root image: /home/vagrant/depot_tools/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot
Downloading http://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-linux-sysroot/toolchain/285950/debian_wheezy_arm_sysroot.tgz

build/install-build-deps.sh --arm
build/install-build-deps-android.sh
gclient sync
```

### Compile

```
build/gyp_chromium -Goutput_dir=out_arm 
ninja -C out_arm/Debug chrome
```

#### Errors

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/depot_tools/src$ ninja -C out_arm/Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out_arm/Debug'
[222/18316] CXX obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/audio_coding/codecs/audio_encoder_interface.audio_encoder.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/audio_coding/codecs/audio_encoder_interface.audio_encoder.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DWEBRTC_RESTRICT_LOGGING -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_MODULE_UTILITY_VIDEO -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DLOGGING_INSIDE_WEBRTC -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM_V7 -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM_NEON -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -Igen -I../.. -I../../third_party/webrtc/overrides -I../../third_party -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/vagrant/depot_tools/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -target arm-linux-gnueabihf -march=armv7-a -no-integrated-as -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/home/vagrant/depot_tools/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -O0 -g -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wsign-compare -std=gnu++11  -c ../../third_party/webrtc/modules/audio_coding/codecs/audio_encoder.cc -o obj/third_party/webrtc/modules/audio_coding/codecs/audio_encoder_interface.audio_encoder.o
/tmp/audio_encoder-f5366d.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/audio_encoder-f5366d.s:559: Internal error!
Assertion failure in get_line_subseg at ../../gas/dwarf2dbg.c line 262.
Please report this bug.
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[222/18316] ACTION Generating resources from app/generated_resources.grd
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Looking forward to some recommendations and leads

### Following instructions by **eyoung100**, still getting an error but further

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data/buildhost/src$ ninja -C out/Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[369/18783] CXX obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -Igen -I../.. -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /vagrant_data/buildhost/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang strict-virtual-specifiers -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -target arm-linux-gnueabihf -march=armv7-a -no-integrated-as -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/vagrant_data/buildhost/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -O0 -g -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wsign-compare -std=gnu++11  -c ../../mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/array_internal.cc -o obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o
/tmp/array_internal-a7a8d2.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/array_internal-a7a8d2.s:1182: Internal error!
Assertion failure in get_line_subseg at ../../gas/dwarf2dbg.c line 262.
Please report this bug.
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[369/18783] ACTION Generating resources from app/generated_resources.grd
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### Posted issue on other Google group:

[This same issue when cross-compiling on Precise64 VM](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/chromium-dev/6WhfEJHuGeE)

[The error I get when cross-compiling on Trusty64 VM](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/_ktNYi9d42U)

### UPDATE Attempt to cross-compile on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) FAILED

... similar message than with Precise64

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant_data/buildhost/src$ ninja -C out/Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[66/18785] CXX obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o
FAILED: ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -Igen -I../.. -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /vagrant_data/buildhost/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang strict-virtual-specifiers -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -target arm-linux-gnueabihf -march=armv7-a -no-integrated-as -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/vagrant_data/buildhost/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -O0 -g -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables -Wno-undefined-bool-conversion -Wno-tautological-undefined-compare -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wsign-compare -std=gnu++11  -c ../../mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/array_internal.cc -o obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.array_internal.o
/tmp/array_internal-227b6c.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/array_internal-227b6c.s:1180: Internal error!
Assertion failure in get_line_subseg at ../../gas/dwarf2dbg.c line 271.
Please report this bug.
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[66/18785] CXX obj/mojo/public/cpp/bindings/lib/mojo_cpp_bindings.message_queue.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### On Precise64 when `clang=False` FAILED

When using `chromium.gyp_env` (no env. variables)

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data/buildhost/src$ more ../chromium.gyp_env 
{ 'GYP_DEFINES': 'target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1 clang=False', 'GYP_CROSSCOMPILE': 'True', }
```

I get this

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data/buildhost/src$ ninja -C out/Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[2/18785] CC obj/third_party/libwebp/dsp/libwebp_dsp.enc_sse2.o
FAILED: cc -MMD -MF obj/third_party/libwebp/dsp/libwebp_dsp.enc_sse2.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -Igen -I../../third_party/libwebp -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/vagrant_data/buildhost/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -O0 -g -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables   -c ../../third_party/libwebp/dsp/enc_sse2.c -o obj/third_party/libwebp/dsp/libwebp_dsp.enc_sse2.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=neon’
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=hard’
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’
../../third_party/libwebp/dsp/enc_sse2.c:1:0: error: bad value (generic-armv7-a) for -mtune= switch
../../third_party/libwebp/dsp/enc_sse2.c:1:0: error: bad value (armv7-a) for -march= switch
../../third_party/libwebp/dsp/enc_sse2.c:1:0: error: bad value (generic-armv7-a) for -mtune= switch
[2/18785] ACTION Generating libudev0 library loader
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### On Precise64 when export env. variables `clang=0`

When

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data/buildhost/src$ env | grep GYP
GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
GYP_DEFINES=target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1 clang=0
```

I get this error

```
$ ninja -C out/Debug chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[6/18785] CXX obj/components/crash/app/crash_component_lib.crash_reporter_client.o
FAILED: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -MMD -MF obj/components/crash/app/crash_component_lib.crash_reporter_client.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -Igen -I../.. -I../../breakpad/src -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb --sysroot=/vagrant_data/buildhost/src/chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -O0 -g -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wsign-compare -Wno-abi  -c ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.cc -o obj/components/crash/app/crash_component_lib.crash_reporter_client.o
In file included from ../../base/basictypes.h:18:0,
                 from ../../base/strings/string16.h:33,
                 from ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.h:10,
                 from ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.cc:5:
../../base/macros.h:165:3: error: identifier ‘static_assert’ will become a keyword in C++0x [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
../../base/macros.h: In function ‘Dest bit_cast(const Source&)’:
../../base/macros.h:165:3: error: there are no arguments to ‘static_assert’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘static_assert’ must be available [-fpermissive]
../../base/macros.h:165:3: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
In file included from ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.h:10:0,
                 from ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.cc:5:
../../base/strings/string16.h: At global scope:
../../base/strings/string16.h:67:3: error: expected identifier before ‘sizeof’
../../base/strings/string16.h:67:3: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘sizeof’
../../base/strings/string16.h:67:3: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘static_assert’ with no type [-fpermissive]
In file included from ../../base/files/file_path.h:111:0,
                 from ../../components/crash/app/crash_reporter_client.cc:7:
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:171:61: error: ‘>>’ operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++0x [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:171:61: note: suggest parentheses around ‘>>’ expression
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:171:61: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:172:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:177:61: error: ‘>>’ operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++0x [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:177:61: note: suggest parentheses around ‘>>’ expression
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:177:61: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:178:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:184:42: error: ‘>>’ operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++0x [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:184:42: note: suggest parentheses around ‘>>’ expression
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:184:42: error: spurious ‘>>’, use ‘>’ to terminate a template argument list
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:185:1: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘using’
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:186:68: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:191:42: error: ‘>>’ operator will be treated as two right angle brackets in C++0x [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:191:42: note: suggest parentheses around ‘>>’ expression
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:191:42: error: spurious ‘>>’, use ‘>’ to terminate a template argument list
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:192:1: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘using’
../../base/containers/hash_tables.h:192:76: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
[6/18785] ACTION Generating resources from blink_resources.grd
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### Compilation complete SUCCESS

On Precise64 4GB memory Vagrant VM

#### Environment

```
GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
GYP_DEFINES=target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1
```

and built in Release mode

```
ninja -v -C out/Release chrome

vagrant@vagrant:~/chromium/buildhost/src/out/Release$ ls
build.ninja             gen         icudtl.dat              libpdf.so      nacl_bootstrap_raw       nacl_irt_arm.nexe.debug.raw  protoc                             resources          yasm
chrome                  genmacro    java_mojo               libpdf.so.TOC  nacl_helper              natives_blob.bin             pseudo_locales                     resources.pak
chrome.1                genmodule   keyboard_resources.pak  libyuv.a       nacl_helper_bootstrap    obj                          pyproto                            snapshot_blob.bin
chrome_100_percent.pak  genperf     lib                     libyuv_neon.a  nacl_irt_arm.nexe        obj.host                     re2c                               tls_edit
chrome-wrapper          genstring   libffmpegsumo.so        locales        nacl_irt_arm.nexe.cmd    pnacl                        remoting_locales                   xdg-mime
```

with

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/chromium/buildhost/src/out/Release$ ls -alh chrome
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 39M Jan 12 22:47 chrome
```

## [Click here to reply on How do I install Chrome on my bare Linux 3.0.8 armv7l?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178874/how-do-i-install-chromium-for-arm-on-bare-linux-3-0-8-armv7l)

Comment: Start Over, Clear out your build directory, Install the Depot Tools, and Follow [Recipe 2](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumArm#Recipe2:_Explicit_Cross_compiling).  Let me know the results...

Comment: Ok I get it. I start over, with a clean environment and without settings CC, CXX etc. See my question updated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now that I'm at work, I'll write up a step by step answer.  First off you seem to be doing the steps in the wrong order.  As such, I'll number these steps in the order they should be executed.

1. `mkdir -pv ~/chromium`
2. `cd ~/chromium`
3. `git config --global user.name “Joel Maranhao”`
4. `git config --global user.email “youremail@example.com”`
5. `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
6. `git config --global core.filemode false`
7. `git config --global color.ui true`
8. `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools`
9. `export PATH=$PATH:~/chromium/depot_tools` **See Update Notes 1**
10. `mkdir -v ~/chromium/buildhost` **See Update Note 2**
11. `cd ../buildhost` **See Update Note 2**
12. `fetch --nohooks chromium`
13. `cd src && ./build/install-build-deps.sh` **See Note 3**
14. `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
15. `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
16. `./build/install-build-deps.sh --arm` **See Note 3**
17. `gclient sync`
18. `GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
    GYP_DEFINES=target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1` **See Note 4**
19. `gclient runhooks`
20. `ninja -C out/Debug chrome`

---

Notice Steps 17 - 19.  Step 18 replaces the Export Statements from Recipe 2 in the file chromium.gyp_env (This effectively switches the build Compiler to `clang`).  Step 19 imports the chromium.gyp_env settings, and will run the proper buildscripts in the proper order.

### Warning: Testing Steps

I'll test these steps on my XUbuntu VM and report back/update etc.

---

### Update Notes

1. Making the change permanent to the `PATH` variable is advisable if you are gong to do this more than once.  Find the following:

`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi`

in `$HOME\.profile`.  Add
`PATH=$PATH:~/chromium/depot_tools`, so that the final `if` looks like:

`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    PATH=$PATH:~/chromium/depot_tools
fi`

If Needed, create a `$HOME/bin` directory (It did not exist on my VM), then logout and back in again.

---

2. From Studying your Post, while downloading the Gigs and Gigs of data from the repository, I see that you ran the `fetch` script and downloaded the Source Code into the `depot_tools` directory.  This is a common mistake and is easily remedied by creating a separate directory, as I've done. This keeps the tools needed to manage and manipulate the build files separate from the items you are building.  This also ensures that the items you are building aren't *polluted* by the tools used to build them.
3. The first pass of `build-deps.sh` downloads all the build tools regardless of cross-compiling or not.  Step 14 and 15 are needed in case the script complains about Held Packages.  The 2nd Pass(Step 16), sets up the cross compile.  I'll update this note as the build progresses.
4. For some reason the OP and I both had trouble with the `gyp_env` file.  Because of this, I have updated Step 18 to include the needed exports.  If interested in using the `gyp_env` file, see the [Gyp User Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation), [Configuring the Builds](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation), and [Common Gyp Build Parameters](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation)

Comment: and I am still getting `/tmp/audio_encoder-b5b761.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/audio_encoder-b5b761.s:559: Internal error!
` on `step [98/18755]` I will start over tomorrow in my morning (I am sitting in France). Thanks for the detailed steps they make sense to me. Did you have more success on your side? I am running a Precise64 vagrant box

Comment: @joelmaranhao  I'm now on Step 13  The downlload Timed out overnight.

Comment: Yes I am also getting these timeouts. It can take a few hours to get everything. I am still getting the same Internal errors. I will keep updating my questions w/ new outcomes.

Comment: Step 15 `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf` Fails with "E: Unable to locate package"

Comment: Use `apt-cache search -multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf`  I'm using 14.10 so 4.8 may be 4.6 etc.

Comment: You are correct, it's 4.6 on 12.04 VM. Is 4.8 a hard requirement. (I suppose I ought to start setting up a 14.10 VM). Shall I continue with 4.6? Now running `sudo apt-get install g++-4.6-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf`

Comment: Not if `/build/install-build-deps.sh` doesn't report an error during the first pass.  If it complains replace 4.8 in step 15 with 4.6 and rerun `/build/install-build-deps.sh`

Comment: On step 20: `ninja: Entering directory out/Debug'
ninja: error: ../../native_client/toolchain/.tars/linux_x86/nacl_arm_newlib.json', needed by 'gen/sdk/linux_x86/nacl_arm_newlib/nacl_arm_newlib.json', missing and no known rule to make it` ... the file is in another folder. Found it in `./buildhost/src/native_client/toolchain_revisions/nacl_arm_newlib.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20131/discussion-between-joelmaranhao-and-eyoung100).

Comment: "Notice Steps 15 - 17. Step 15 replaces the Export Statements from Recipe 2" don't seems to match the step numbers. Can you confirm?

Comment: I am not getting any luck, I stuck on another error at `[369/18783]` I will update my question accordingly. On step 18 shouldn't it be `'GYP_CROSSCOMPILE': '1'`. I exported manually to `env` in the meantime. Now building my environment on Ubuntu 14.04 VM

Comment: True is 1.  Its a binary variable

Comment: I am running out of luck. I seem to get a similar error on `14.04 (Trusty)`, see update in my Question. I am downloading Ubuntu `14.10 server (Unicorn)`, just in case. I am guessing that you did compile and didn't stumble upon those ... so I must have done something different. That puzzles me. I just don't understand what is the error I am getting. `clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 `

Comment: Lets try the default linux compiler.  See update to step 18.

Comment: Yes I was trying that too. And had a different [error (see my post at the end of this thread)](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/_ktNYi9d42U). I am trying to reproduce it again today and I will update my question accordingly. Seriously thanks you for following up on this. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posted the error I get when `{ 'GYP_DEFINES': 'target_arch=arm arm_float_abi=hard component=shared_library linux_use_gold_flags=1 clang=False', 'GYP_CROSSCOMPILE': 'True', }
` on Precise64 (In the meantime I am still building my 14.10 setup)

Comment: the results I get differ depending on whether I set the env. variables or use `chromiums_gyp.env` (?) ... see my question updated.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere :)  It won't matter whether you use False/0 or True/1.  We need to test compile using GCC for ARM, so crosscompile must be True/1 and Clang must be False/0.  What is the output of `echo ${CXXFLAGS}`?  What is the output of `uname -a` in the Vagrant box?

Comment: eyound100 it's compiling now!!  and it has never been that far in the compilation Oh YEAH! I will reply to you question when complete. Just now it's compiling with the clang++. I have increased the memory of the VM and exported variables instead of the `chromiums.gyp_env` ... Next step would be how to install? does it create a `rootfs` folder?

Comment: Update your question with the output once the compile has finished and we'll install it

Comment: The compilation went through when `ninja -v -C out/Release chrome
` The Debug mode gives me the issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have created a new question for [How to install cross-compiled Chromium for ARM onto bare Linux 3.0.8?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178874/how-do-i-install-chromium-for-arm-on-bare-linux-3-0-8-armv7l) You have address this first topic very well. It's very appreciated. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20210/discussion-between-joelmaranhao-and-eyoung100).