# How do I install Chromium for ARM Cortex-A8 on bare Linux 3.0.8 armv7l?

Tags: chrome, arm, cross-compilation

#### TARGET [FriendlyARM mini210s](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210s)

I have successfully cross-compiled Chromium for ARM [SEE WORKFLOW HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm).

### How do I install the Chromium on my bare linux 3.0.8 armv7l?

#### What I have done so far

I copied over `./chrome/installer/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot` files onto my target (not sure that was the right thing, but it seems reasonable enough)

When I try to run Chrome I am getting this error:

```
[root@target chrome-release]# ./chrome
./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libattr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE I resolved this particular issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180099/chromium-compiled-for-arm-libattr-so-1-not-found)

QUESTION 1 : Where do I find `libattr` source or binary and install it on my target?

I have found a file, but I'd rather try to x-compile from source.

QUESTION 2 :  How do I have resolved consistantly without breaking my target?

[This helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) ... but I feel that I am messing my Linux 3.0.8 armv7l instance.

```
[root@target chrome-release]# ./chrome
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./chrome)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chrome)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libkeyed_service_content.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libkeyed_service_content.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libkeyboard.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libbase_prefs.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libstorage.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libstorage.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libnet.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libnet.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgfx.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgfx.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmessage_center.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libviews.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libviews.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libevents_devices.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcontent.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcontent.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libv8.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libv8.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdbus.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libskia.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libppapi_proxy.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libppapi_proxy.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libprinting.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdomain_reliability.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libapp_list.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmojo_common_lib.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libblink_web.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libblink_web.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgcm.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmedia.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmedia.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libbase_i18n.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libui_base.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libui_base.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libstorage_common.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libppapi_host.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libsessions_content.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcc.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcc.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libbase.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libbase.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libevents_base.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/liburl_matcher.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgin.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcompositor.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libash.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libash.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmojo_system_impl.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgtk2ui.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgtk2ui.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libpolicy_component.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libpolicy_component.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libsql.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libblink_platform.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdevice_bluetooth.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdevice_bluetooth.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/liburl_lib.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcrcrypto.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcrcrypto.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libaura.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libipc.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libipc.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libsync_core.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgpu.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgpu.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgesture_detection.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libevents.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libppapi_shared.so)
./chrome: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0)
./chrome: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0)
./chrome: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcc_surfaces.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libcc_surfaces.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdevice_battery.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libdevice_battery.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libwebkit_gpu.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgl_wrapper.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libmedia_blink.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgpu_blink.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libipc_mojo.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgles2_utils.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgles2_implementation.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgles2_implementation.so)
./chrome: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
./chrome: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libwtf_unittest_helpers.so)
./chrome: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /sdcard/chrome-release/lib/libgl_in_process_context.so)
./chrome: /lib/libresolv.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3)
```

### UPDATE - Install on mini210s w/ linux 3.0.8 armv7l target

When I try this:

```
# LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc-2.13.so;/lib/libresolv-2.13.so ./chrome -v
Segmentation fault
```

How do get more information about the reason of this segmentation fault?

```
$ file ./chrome
./chrome: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, not stripped
```

How do I know whether this compiled file should run on my SBC w/ linuc 3.0.8 armv7l?

Also asked on [chromium-dev group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/_8VUllVuMyc)

### UPDATE Tried to install on BeagleBone Black

```
root@beaglebone:~/chromium# uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone67 #1 SMP Wed Sep 24 21:30:03 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am getting the same segmentation fault

```
root@beaglebone:~/chromium# ./chrome
Segmentation fault
```

Determine file type

```
root@beaglebone:~/chromium# file chrome
chrome: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x99f2a5210e0831419cf2bb4c9c64839cf03673f4, not stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the `libattr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` issue, I have downloaded an `armhf` version of the library [here](http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/fatdog/arm/packages/beta/libattr-2.4.47-armhf-1.tbz) and installed on my SBC, but I still have the SEGFAULT issue