# How do I compile Chromium for ARM Cortex-A8?

Tags: chrome, arm, cross-compilation

I do understand the workflow for compiling Chromium for ARM [posted on here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm).

The target is **Linux 3.0.8 armv7l**

I am able to produce a binary, but trying to run it on target, I get a segmentation fault.

```
$ file ./chrome
./chrome: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, not stripped
```

I am guessing that the binary produced still doesn't match completely the architecture of the target [FriendlyARM mini210s Cortex-A8](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210s).

Any pointers in that direction are most welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cross-compile Chromium for ARM?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm)

Comment: I posted this question but I am looking for help for that specific ARM Cortex-A8 architecture. Different compilation flags may apply (?). I am new with this. I am just asking as different topic instead of cluttering that other question.

Comment: Why exactly do you think it doesn't match the target architecture? What does `file chrome_binary` say?

Comment: See my question updated with info. The target is mini210s Cortex-A8 ... I figured that Cortex-A8 may matter since I had used the flag `-mtune=cortex-8` for cross-compiling other tools before... and I haven't done this kind of tuning for Chromium x-compiling (?). I am totally a newbie on this one.

Comment: Actually I had posted the question differently before. Check [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178874/how-do-i-install-chromium-for-arm-cortex-a8-on-bare-linux-3-0-8-armv7l). I figured that it was the way I installed that caused the segmentation fault (dependencies??)

Comment: Yes the 3 questions are probably from me. I am trying to figure it out, I have spent a great deal of time learning about this. Don't assume that I am posting without any grounds. Saying that you may have found interesting stuff and not sharing is not great. It's actually a bit lame. Next time don't bother