# chromium compiled for ARM, libattr.so.1 not found

Tags: chrome, arm, shared-library

### Env.

```
# uname -a
Linux FriendlyARM 3.0.8-FriendlyARM #1 PREEMPT Tue Oct 30 10:33:04 CST 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

### Problem

When trying to run my chrome executable I am getting this:

```
[root@FriendlyARM chromium]# ./chrome
./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libattr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Print shared library dependencies, indeed `libattr.so.1` is not found

```
ldd ./chrome

...
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x469ab000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXau.so.6 (0x469be000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x469c8000)
libattr.so.1 => not found      <======= NOT FOUND
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x469d3000)
```

I have found a `libattr.so.1` library that I copied to `/usr/lib` and created a symbolic link to `/lib`

but chrome still can't find it.

What could I try to fix this?

#### UPDATE 20150120

```
file libXau.so.6.0.0
debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXau.so.6.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xcbd329ab335e695742bac844bfcb02c83e8fac78, stripped

file libattr.so.1.1.0
libattr.so.1.1.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

#### Readelf libattr

```
$ readelf -A libattr.so.1.1.0 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1        <=====
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1    <=====
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP    <=============
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
```

#### Readelf libXau

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data$ readelf -A libXau.so.6.0.0 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2      <=====
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP   <=======
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

or with `grep FP`

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data$ readelf -A libattr.so.1.1.0  | grep FP
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP

vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data$ readelf -A libXau.so.6.0.0 | grep FP
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers    <===== CONFIRM it's ARMHF (?)
```

Apparently my `libattr` is not is not using the correct ABI. I found another library that should work better [here](http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/fatdog/arm/packages/beta/libattr-2.4.47-armhf-1.tbz)

### ARMHF libattr

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant_data/libattr-2.4.47-armhf-1/lib$ readelf -A libattr.so.1.1.0 | grep FP
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
```

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXau.so.6` (which is known to be okay) and `file /usr/lib/libattr.so.1` ?

Comment: See update in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show the output of `file libattr.so.1.1.0`, but the executable is looking for `libattr.so.1`. That's not the same name. Normally `libattr.so.1` should be a symbolic link to `libattr.so.1.1.0`, and the right way to create this symbolic link is to run the program `ldconfig`. So make sure that you put `libattr.so.1.1.0` where you want it (`/usr/local/lib` would be a good idea, `/usr/lib` is for files installed by the package manager) and that you have run `ldconfig`. Run `ldconfig -v` and check that it tells you that it created the desired symbolic link.

If that's not the issue, it's possible that you grabbed an incompatible `libattr.so.1`. There are several [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s on ARM, depending on which instructions programs are allowed to use (allowing programs to use more instructions limits them to recent, high-end processors). Your system is evidently based on `gnueabihf`, i.e. [ARM EABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0036b/index.html) with GNU libc and with hardware floating point (“hard float”) support — the [armhf](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort) architecture of Debian. Make sure that `libattr.so.1` is also from armhf and not e.g. from armeabi (ARM EABI without hardware floating point). You can check the ABI that a library (or an executable) is for with `readelf -A libattr.so.1 libXau.so.6.0.0`. Look in particular for `Tag_ABI_VFP_args` — the values must match.

Comment: I have updated my question with the `readelf` output. It looks fine. I also created the symbolic link with `ldconfig` but I am still getting the error and the library is still not found. Thanks for the tips, they are great help, I am learning.

Comment: Ok `Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers` confirms that `libXau.so.6.0.0` if `armhf` right? however `libattr.so.1.1.0` doesn't have that tag. Does it mean it's `armel`? Where do I find an `armhf` version of the `libattr`?

Comment: Ok I resolved the `libattr` not found issue, but now I have `SEGFAULT` when starting chromium. But I think you pretty much answered my initial question. Thanks

Comment: @joelmaranhao Yes, sorry, it's `Tag_ABI_VFP_args` that makes the distinction between armel and armhf. You should be able to find a suitable libattr in the armhf architecture of Debian (https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/libattr1/download).