# Running Chromium on ARM - Failed to load NSS libraries

Tags: libraries, chrome, arm

**TARGET**: FriendlyARM mini210s / Linux 3.0.8 armv7l

Cross-compiled for ARM using [this workflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm)

Install `sysroot` on target and tried to run Chrome

```
# ./chrome
[0122/142305:ERROR:nss_util.cc(981)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[0122/142305:FATAL:nacl_helper_linux.cc(482)] Check failed: is_init_process == nacl_sandbox->layer_one_enabled() (0 vs. 1)
[1227:1227:0122/142305:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(296)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
[1227:1227:0122/142305:ERROR:nss_util.cc(981)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[1225:1225:0122/142306:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(216)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[1225:1225:0122/142306:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(216)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

### Checked NSS libraries

```
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/nss/ /usr/lib/nss

ldconfig

[root@FriendlyARM Release]# ldconfig -v | grep nss
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus.so.2
        libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis.so.2
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod.so.2
        libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files.so.2
        libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns.so.2
        libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat.so.2
        libnssutil3.so -> libnssutil3.so
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus.so
        libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis.so
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod.so
        libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files.so
        libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns.so
        libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat.so
        libnss3.so -> libnss3.so
        libgnutls-openssl.so.27 -> libgnutls-openssl.so.27.0.0
        libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.11.so
        libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.11.so
        libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.11.so
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.11.so
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.11.so
        libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.11.so
        libnss_db.so.2 -> libnss_db.so.2
```

### UPDATE: RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND=1

```
[root@FriendlyARM Release]# export RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND=1
```

and the NaCl issue is gone... yet I am not sure what it is meant for

```
[root@FriendlyARM Release]# ./chrome
[1298:1298:0122/184252:ERROR:nss_util.cc(981)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[1296:1296:0122/184252:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(216)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[1296:1296:0122/184252:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(216)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```